# I wish to learn few suktams from Veda Samhitas. Is there any guru willing to teach me online?

Tags: vedas, guru, samhita, purusha-sukta

Sorry if this is an ignorant question. There has been mixed response to the question whether suktams such as Purusha, Sri, Nasadiya can be chanted without initiation by a guru. I do not want to make any mistakes in pronunciation and understanding.
I would prefer an online guru if I need to be initiated. Also can women be initiated?